# Exclude domain from Varnish stats/hits

Tags: varnish

On my server I've installed Varnish, and there are two sites, on apache. One of this , Drupal based, uses varnish integration.

The other one, wordpress based, does not use Varnish, and in my default.vcl any resource from this domain is "missed" (because I can't install a plugin that communicates with Varnish).

The problem is that my varnishstat, or varnishhist, output is "dirty": I've many "miss" entry for wordpress site, instead I would like to have stats only for the drupal based site.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily by adding a couple of VCL lines at the **beginning** of your **config.vcl**:

```
import std;
sub vcl_miss {
    std.log("Backend: " + req.backend);
}
sub vcl_pass {
    std.log("Backend: " + req.backend);
}
sub vcl_hit {
    std.log("Backend: " + req.backend);
}
sub vcl_pipe {
    std.log("Backend: " + req.backend);
}
```

Then, tweak your **varnishncsa** command :

```
varnishncsa -m VCL_Log:Backend:\ drupal
```

Ditto for **varnishhist** or any other varnish utilities.

Answer (score 1):

varnishstat/varnishhist don't have an option to filter things and they read form the in-memory log varnishd.
There are several approaches to solve your problem, one could be to run different varnish instances, one for wordpress one for drupal and a a third one that acts as a dispatcher between both (You could run them on the same machine using different ports and varnish instance names).

OTOH, you could try to make wordpress "use" the varnish, I did not really get why you would need to have wordpress configured for varnish. Simply configure varnish for wordpress. :)
E.g. here is a howto: https://www.varnish-software.com/blog/step-step-speed-wordpress-varnish-software

If you cannot to that for whatever reason, you could try to make the "dirty" requests look better in the log. Calling pipe could be a solution for that. (Pipe can be called from vcl_recv as well. Pipe short circuits the client and the backend connections and Varnish will just sit there and shuffle)

It should work like this
if ( req.url ~ /wordpress/.*) {  return(pipe);  }

rgds,
j.